# Way to make SilverLight progressbar look good?

Tags: silverlight, animation, user-controls, progress-bar

I have been playing around with the Silverlight progressbar a while and no matter what color (Foreground) I set it too it stays dull and ugly-ish.

I wonder why this is since I'm using Silverlight 5.0 on a windows 7 machine, .NET 4.5 and the windows 7 default progressbar looks stunning.

I searched a lot for it and I did find some commercial solutions where you could pay to get prettier controls, but I don't want to do that (since it may not work for all I know).

How can I make my progressbar look nicer?

Comment: I know its not a critical feature, but all programs can benefit from a little WOW effect...
Especially when you are being graded by silly superficial school teachers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have a look at the [blacklight controls](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/).
In my opinien the loading animation is really nice (It is not a progress bar, but if you add a percentage loaded display it is kind of ;) ). You can find it under animated controls.

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Answer (score 2):

Use styles or themes to change the visual of progress bar. You can get the copy of the style of the control in Blend as described [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/using-blend-to-find-default-style-xaml/).

Comment: I would like to accept both answers, but the other guys was a bit longer and he has fewer points. Thanks a lot anyways!